# How to create button to change between textures in TREE.js?

Tags: javascript, button, three.js, textures, collada

I hava collada model (.dae) and I displayed this model using this code

```
            var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {

                scene.add( car );

            } );

            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var texture = textureLoader.load('./model/Car_Red.jpg');
            loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
            loader.load( './car.dae', function ( collada ) {
                car = collada.scene;
                car.traverse(function (node) {

                      if (node.isMesh)
                      {
                          node.material.map = texture;
                      }
                 });
             } );
```

Now , I have multiple texture (.jpg) and need to create button to switch between them ,any idea please ?

Comment: You can add a button to your HTML and `addEventListener("click", changeTexture)`. Your `changeTexture` function should look similar to the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks , I will try this